# Accessing sql-array item by in jooq

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jooq

How can I access item of array in JOOQ like in this sql-query?

```
SELECT (ARRAY_AGG(id))[1]
FROM entities;
```

Something like that:

```
dsl().select(arrayAgg(ENTITIES.ID).get(1)).from(ENTITIES).fetch();
```

Or just access to first item:

```
dsl().select(arrayAgg(ENTITIES.ID).head()).from(ENTITIES).fetch();
```

I know about string solution, but it's not good:

```
field("(ARRAY_AGG(id))[1]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.8, this is not possible out of the box. There's a pending feature request for array element access:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/229

#### Why Java cannot offer this functionality

One of the problems is API design here. A post-fix method as you suggested cannot return the appropriate type. Consider this API design:

```
interface Field<T> {
    Field<???> get(int index); // What type to return here?
}
```

In Java, it is not possible to put any additional constraints on the class's generic type parameter `<T>` on a per-method level, as in the following hypothetical code using something like a "partial method" (i.e. a method that is available only on some subtypes of `Field<T>`, namely those where `T` is an array):

```
interface Field<T> {
    @If(T instanceof E[])
    Field<E> get(int index);
}
```

#### Workaround

But you can write your own workaround. For instance:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Field<T> elementAt(Field<T[]> arrayField, int index) {
    return DSL.field("{0}[{1}]", 
        (Class<T>) arrayField.getType().getComponentType(),
        arrayField, DSL.inline(index)
    );
}
```

You can now use it as such:

```
dsl().select(elementAt(arrayAgg(ENTITIES.ID), 1))
     .from(ENTITIES)
     .fetch();
```